# Lock individual application's interface

Tags: scripts, password, lock-screen, xdotool

Can I lock a particular application's interface without locking the whole screen? It would be very useful at work to be able to leave certain applications open when leaving my desk as colleagues often access my desktop to add changes. I would however like to lock out pidgin/skype/firefox/thunderbird so that it remains logged in but unusable/unviewable without a separate password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Hide windows of applications, password to make them visible again

An edited version of [this script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581572/how-can-i-prevent-people-to-see-what-applications-i-have-opened/581750#581750) will (completely) hide/show interfaces (windows) of *any* application, listed in the head section of the script (toggle).

It has a "mild" password protection, since the password is stored inside the script. The key combination to run the script will be another barrier that will prevent access too easily. That will probably be sufficient in the situation you mention, but you'll have to decide.

[image]

#### How to use

1. The script uses both `xdotool` and `wmctrl`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool wmctrl
   ```
2. Then simply copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `password_app.py`, change if you want the current password "Monkey" in the line:

   ```
   if passw == "Monkey":
   ```
3. In the head section of the script, add applications you need/want to hide the interface from. As an example, I set:

   ```
   applications = ["gedit", "thunderbird"]
   ```
4. Test-run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/password_app.py
   ```

   You need the password for both hiding and showing your interface:
5. If all works fine, add it to a shortcut key combination: Choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/password_app.py
   ```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import getpass
import os
import time

#---
applications = ["gedit", "thunderbird"]
#---

get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8").strip()

def toggle():
    windowlist = os.environ["HOME"]+"/"+".windowlist.txt"
    user = getpass.getuser()
    wlist = [l for l in get("wmctrl -lp").splitlines()]
    procs = sum([[p.split()[0] for p in get("ps -u "+user).splitlines() if app in p] for app in applications], [])
    matches = sum([[l.split()[0] for l in wlist if p in l] for p in procs], [])
    if len(matches) != 0:
        with open(windowlist, "a+") as out:
            for match in matches:
                out.write(match+"\n")
                subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", "xdotool windowunmap "+match])
    else:
        try:
            with open(windowlist) as r:
                for l in r.readlines():
                    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", "xdotool windowmap "+l])
            os.remove(windowlist)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

try:
    cmd = "zenity --entry --title='Restricted!' --text='Enter your _password:'"
    passw = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8").strip()
    if passw == "Monkey":
        time.sleep(1)
        toggle()
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    pass
```

#### Notes

- This does not prevent users from opening *new instances* of the applications, it hides the current ones. All can be done however with additional coding :).
- If another user might open a new instance of a listed application, running the script will first add those windows to the hidden windows. *All* windows will then show up on the next run of the script.

Comment: @Oceanic_Panda to be honest, I *love* this kind of questions :)

Answer (score 0):

An application that has been designed to take advantage of additional user privileges like <kbd>System Settings</kbd> - <kbd>User accounts</kbd> *can* do this.

An application like Thunderbird which has not been designed like that cannot out-of-the-box.  Therefore your have two possibilities:

1. Dust off your programming skills and add the functionality yourself
2. Create a different user for Thunderbird and `su` into the user when you need to read the mail and keep it closed if you don't...